# Lazy Loading Modules with Angular and Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services SPA Templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm having an issue with lazyloading Angular modules.

I've created a Github repo here: https://github.com/mpalmer-sps/PluralSightNg2Fundamentals

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the Microsoft ASP.NET Core JavaScript Services SPATemplate for Angular (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices)

I'm trying to add a User module using a lazy load implementation but the approach outlined in the Angular documented approach does not work despite the syntax being correct.

The error is the following:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/user/user.module'. webpackEmptyContext@http://localhost:3258
```

The user.module is referenced in the app.module.shared.ts file:

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren:'app/user/user.module#UsersModule'}
```

however, this doesn't work even when trying different path strings.

The workaround for this is to abandon lazyloading and modify some pieces starting with the navigation link in the navbar.component.html file to the following:

```
[routerLink]="['/profile']" routerLinkActive="active">Welcome User
```

and then add the UserModule reference to the app.module.shared.ts file

This works but lazyloading doesn't appear to be happening.

Whereas the lazyload approach would be the following:

```
[routerLink]="['/user/profile']" routerLinkActive="active">Welcome User
```

and then adding the path with the loadChildren syntax and removing the UserModule as shown in the app.module.shared.ts file

Has anyone run into this?